# Can't complete texlive install

Tags: texlive, tex-core, ubuntu

I'm trying to install tex live in Ubuntu 20.04. In a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

but I didn't realize there wasn't enough space, so I get an error during install.
Now, I have no clue how to solve this because I can't use `apt remove` or `purge` to make more space because of this error:

> E: Dependencies not fulfilled. Try "apt --fix-broken install" with no packages (or specify a solution)

When I try that, it says that it will download more, but it causes the same error as before.
Please help.

Comment: this is really just an apt question not about tex, so not on topic but doesn't apt have a forced remove option (there is a forced=yes option but check the manual "dangerous option")

Comment: If your /home is in the same partition,  use some tool  to detect where you have a lot of space wasted  (movies, etc.)  and delete it  (or move it to an external drive) and try the fix